# Edit "new discussion" text in discussions list

Tags: web-part, 2013, discussion-board, community

Hi in sharepoint 2013 community site home page you can see a webpart named "discussions list". In that webpart I wanted to edit "new discussion" text. Webpart properties also has no option to edit that text. Is there a way to edit this text or it cannot be edited??

Comment: No answer, but I need to be able to do this as well. In the previous version, was able to accomplish changing "add new discussion" to "add new assignment" using a content editor reference to a site asset document containing the necessary code. With the upgrade to 2013, this revision has been lost. Looking for a 2013 resolution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add JavaScript to the page to change the element's display text.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("a:contains('new discussion')").html("Your new Text");
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer for me. The only thing I would add is to to change your jQuery statement to the following otherwise the little + sign dissapears:  $("a:contains('new discussion')").html("<span class=\"ms-list-addnew-imgSpan20\"><img src=\"/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23\" class=\"ms-list-addnew-img20\"></span><span>NEW WHATEVER HERE</span>");

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean to edit an existing discussion. If I'm correct, Click on the Subject of the discussion item (hyperlink).. you'll see the item with "Like, Reply and  ..."

Click on "..." and you'll be presented with an option to "Edit".

Comment: No you have misunderstood the question. What I want is in the home page to start a new discussion there is a hyperlike named "new discussion". Is it possible to edit that text??